# how to add object at specified index in NSMutable array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

**How can I add object at specified index?**
in my problem

`NSMutableArray *substring` 
contains index and object alternatively
and I need to add it to the another  array `str` according to index I getting from this array.

```
NSMutableArray *str=[NSMutableArray new];

if ([substrings containsObject:@"Category-Sequence:"]) 
{

    NSString *index=[substrings objectAtIndex:5];
    //[substrings objectAtIndex:5] 
gives me integer position at which I need to add object in `str` array,
gives 5,4,8,2,7,1 etc

    NSString *object=[substrings objectAtIndex:1];

    //[substrings objectAtIndex:1] gives object,gives NSString type of object

    [str insertObject:object atIndex:(index.intValue)];

}
```

please suggest some way to achieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Preetam : you should post correct code... it give wrong impression... you wrote `nsmutable array str;` is it good?

Comment: Maybe you should indicate what's failing?  Maybe you should specify what index is being returned?

Comment: @HotLicks: no error at all but array 'str' is unable to fill with objects.

Comment: Is it nil?  Most likely it's not been allocated.  (What do you get when you do `NSLog(@"The array is %@", str);`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate the array first & then try to add objects in it.

```
NSMutableArray *str = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
if ([substrings containsObject:@"Category-Sequence:"]) 
{
    NSString *index=[substrings objectAtIndex:5];
    NSString *object=[substrings objectAtIndex:1];

    [str insertObject:object atIndex:(index.intValue)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate the `NSMutableArray` before inserting objects into it:

```
NSMutableArray *strMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

(You’ll also need to release it when you’re done if you’re not using ARC.)

Or you could also use a temporary object, if you don’t need to keep `strMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *strMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Then you can insert objects into the `NSMutableArray`.

Be careful with using indexes of and in different arrays, however. There might be a better way to do what you want.